# Background image for TextField - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add a background image for a TextField in flutter. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Stack(
 alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
 children: <Widget>[
   SizedBox(width:333.0, height:43.0,
     child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/search_field.png')),),
     TextField(
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       controller: _searchController,
       autocorrect: false,
       style: inputTextStyle,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
         filled:false,
     ))],)
```

Unfortunately, I have three problems:

- the text box is stretched to the width of the device and the cursor is blinking to the left of the image
- there is a single line border below the text field
- when the keyboard appears I see an overflow warning (Bottom overflowed by 137 pixels)

[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E199, locale en-US)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the obtained result? Also, what do you mean by "the cursor is blinking to the left of the image".

Answer (score 4):

Stack is not the best sloution for this.
Because in stack position might change from screen to screen.
Try this code:

```
Container(
  child: TextFormField(),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: AssetImage("assets/images/desert.jpg",),
        ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    new Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: 100.0,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: new Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: <Widget>[
        Image(image: AssetImage('assets/example.jpg')),
        TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            autocorrect: false,
            decoration:
                //disable single line border below the text field
                new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Username')),
      ]),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
new Stack(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Image(
      image: AssetImage('assets/search_field.png'),
      width: 333.0,
      height: 43.0,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    Text("someText")
  ],
);
```